# how to show current user data?

Tags: java, spring

how to show current user data?? here I am trying to showing the logged in user post. but I can not solve the problem. i am don't understand how to show current user data.

post controller classs:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/viewcurrentpost")
public String showCurrentPost(Model m, Principal principal) {
    boolean hasPost = false;
    if(principal != null) {
        hasPost = postService.hasPost(principal.getName());
    }
    m.addAttribute("hasPost", hasPost);
    return "viewcurrentpost";
}
```

post service class:

```
public boolean hasPost(String name) {
    if(name == null)
        return false;
    List<Post> post = postDao.getCurrentPost(name);
    if(post.size() == 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

post Dao Class:

```
  public List<Post> getCurrentPost(String username) {
    return jdbc.query("select * from Post, users where post.username=users.username and users.enabled=true and post.username=:username", 
            new MapSqlParameterSource("username", username), new RowMapper<Post>() {

        @Override
        public Post mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            Post post = new Post();
            post.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            post.setImage(rs.getString("image"));
            post.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
            post.setDate(rs.getString("date"));
            post.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            post.setUser(user);
            return post;
            }

        });
    }
```

post view page:

```
<tr>
    <th>ID</th><th>IMAGE</th><th>TITLE</th><th>DATE</th<th>DESCRIPTION</th><th>USERNAME</th><th>ACTION</th>
 </tr>
             <c:forEach var="hasPost" items="${hasPost}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${hasPost.id}</td>
                    <td>${hasPost.image}</td>
                    <td>${hasPost.title}</td>
                    <td>${hasPost.date}</td>
                    <td>${hasPost.description}</td>
                    <td >${hasPost.username}</td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

Comment: You are not sending `post` from controller so it will not work .

Comment: still not working

Comment: No .`hasPost` not list its boolean . You have to send list of `post`

Comment: You have to return a `List` of `Post`s somewhere. Currently you return a `boolean` from your code to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the `List<Post>` from the controller . One thing you can do is. You can get list of post seperately.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/viewcurrentpost")
public String showCurrentPost(Model m, Principal principal) {
    boolean hasPost = false;
    if(principal != null) {
        hasPost = postService.hasPost(principal.getName());
    }
   List<Post> posts = postDao.getCurrentPost(principal.getName());
           m.addAttribute("post", posts);
    m.addAttribute("hasPost", hasPost);

    return "viewcurrentpost";
}
```

In the Html You can send like

```
 <c:forEach var="hasPost" items="${post}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${hasPost.id}</td>
                    <td>${hasPost.image}</td>
                    <td>${hasPost.title}</td>
                    <td>${hasPost.date}</td>
                    <td>${hasPost.description}</td>
                    <td >${hasPost.username}</td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

Comment: its working. and showing current user data.